# How to create a temporary table from a SELECT query in Access VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to get some results (just for viewing) from a query in a small functional method in Access VBA. The query looks like this:

```
sqlstr = "TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfDisclosed Fees (Y/N)]" & _
"SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]" & _
"FROM [Deal Data ECM]" & _
"WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) = 'Y'))" & _
"GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]" & _
"PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];"
```

None of these work:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery sqlstr
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset sqlstr
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr
```

How can I get it to work? There's gotta be an easy way for this simple task. I'm using Access 2003.

Comment: In the end, do you want to take the result set from this and bind it to something to display on your UI?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you run the commands?

Comment: I just want a table to be created/overwritten, so that it is shown to a human who is using the form (who can then make changes to it).

Comment: the errors that I am running into are due to the fact that none of those commands are not meant for crosstab queries with "select" and "transform". 3065 and 2342 are the error numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you took a look at the string you produced using `Debug.Print sqlstr` in code or `?sqlstr` from the command window you'd see

```
TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfDisclosed Fees (Y/N)]SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]FROM [Deal Data ECM]WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) = 'Y'))GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

Then you might notice there's no spaces between one clause and the next.

adding returns where there are spaces makes it a little eaiser to see

```
TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) 
    AS [CountOfDisclosed Fees (Y/N)]SELECT 
    [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]FROM
   [Deal Data ECM]WHERE
   ((([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) = 'Y'))GROUP 
   BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]PIVOT
   [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

Try adding a space before each ending `"`

```
sqlstr = "TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfDisclosed Fees (Y/N)] " & _
"SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type] " & _
"FROM [Deal Data ECM] " & _
"WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) = 'Y')) " & _
"GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type] " & _
"PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region]; "
```

However since you want to create a table you'll need to add a target. By adding an `INTO` clause between the select and from

```
sqlstr = "TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfDisclosed Fees (Y/N)] " & _
"SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type] " & _
"INTO YourNewTable " & _
"FROM [Deal Data ECM] " & _
"WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) = 'Y')) " & _
"GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type] " & _
"PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region]; "
```

Note: Everytime you execute this you'll be deleting the old table. Also note you should use     `DoCmd.RunSQL`

Comment: I tried your solution, but still, none of the commands work. The second option I tried, "CurrentDb.OpenRecordset sqlstr", was the only one of the three that doesn't return an error. Still no luck in creating the table, though.

Comment: I missed that part of your question that you wanted to create a table I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.RunSQL` cannot be used with `SELECT` queries, you need to perform an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`

One option would be to create a table in your database which matches the query output and perform an `INSERT ... SELECT ...`. You can then display the table to the user.

The problem with this approach is needing to delete the table contents each time before running the query again.

Comment: what i'm not understanding is this: if i do a SELECT query, haven't i just retrieved those records from the database? now all that's left to do is display them, which, one would think, would be painfully easy... there has to be a simple way to just create a new table from those rows that were retrieved by SELECT.

Comment: Have you tried creating a query object  and then binding it to a grid or some other control you can put on a form? I'll have a think about this, it's late, if you dont find an answer I'll have another go tomorrow. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested query to create the table. I wasn't able to nest the sql but if you save your query as say `deal_time` then you can use `docmd.runSQL "select * into mytable from deal_time"`